# Styling issue in polymer1.0

Tags: polymer-1.0

> I am not able to assign dynamic value to margin-left of my element inside dom-repeat.

```
 <template id="test" is="dom-repeat" items="{{viewelements}}">
        <span style$="margin-left:{{item.stPt}}">{{item.stPt}}</span>
    </template>
```

Comment: You cannot yet use string interpolation in Polymer 1.0.

Answer (score 0):

Use a computed binding:

```
<template id="test" is="dom-repeat" items="{{viewelements}}">
    <span style$="[[_computedClass(item.stPt)]]">{{item.stPt}}</span>
</template>

-----

_computedClass: function(value) {
  return 'margin-left:' + value + ';'
}
```